# Getting started with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, references

I have been reading a lot about PostGIS, but I am struggling to find a good beginner's guide.

Which tutorials/books do you recommend?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

A good start can be the [PostGIS Manual](http://postgis.net/documentation/) edited by Paul Ramsey.
[Boundless' Introduction to PostGIS](https://gisforthought.com/projects/postgis_tutorial/)

Boundless (formerly opengeo) has a very very good workshop with a lot of exercises on the PostGIS database. I would start with this one.

Some starting points to consider:

- [PostGIS in Action (Second Edition)](http://www.manning.com/obe2/) should be your first resource
- Materials from BostonGIS [webpage](http://www.bostongis.com/)

Also, for general introduction to PostgreSQL I quite enjoyed '[Beginning Databases with PostreSQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594789)' book by Matthew & Stones.

Answer (score 14):

My way to find PostGIS was
http://bostongis.org/?content_name=postgis_tut01#20

there is three parts of the tutorial. I really like it.

Then I have to mention:
http://postgisonline.org

I have tried to build a way of trying spatial SQL queries online. There are a very few tutorials there:
http://postgisonline.org/tutorials

anyone can write a tutorial and use it through the site. Look at http://postgisonline.org/doc
There is still a lot to do with the site but there is not time enough.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [Portable GIS](https://portablegis.xyz/):

> provide beginners with a
> ready-installed and configured stack
> of open source GIS tools that would
> run in windows without the need for
> emulation or a live cdemulation or a live cd

i.e. You can have it up and running on a USB stick.  Very handy for workplace environments.

It has on it:
PostgreSQL (version 8.4)/Postgis (version 1.4)

Answer (score 4):

Since this year (2014), we've got the excellent "PostGIS Cookbook" from Packt publishing [Paolo Corti, Stephen Vincent Mather, Thomas J Kraft, Bborie Park]

Here's the link: http://www.packtpub.com/postgis-to-store-organize-manipulate-analyze-spatial-data-cookbook/book

A lot of cases are explained with working instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this book it's awesome

https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/postgis-essentials

very clear, lot of examples.