# Getting started with storing LoST and GML searching

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgresql, database, gml

I am working on a logging and search database application.

The application will receive event records containing XML LoST values (RFC5222 Location-To-Service-Translation). These records will be stored in a PostgreSQL database.

The application will later need to search for those event records using GML Polygon, Circle, ArcBand or Ellipse areas.

Can someone give me a pointer of where to get started with this?

Comment: Relevant: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/how-do-i-get-started-with-postgis