# File or personal database in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, spatial-database, personal-geodatabase

Is there any database in QGIS? I use ArcMap with a file geodatabase. But now, I have to start a project in QGIS and I don't know, how to create a database.

Comment: you can only read and edit geodatabases in qgis - no creation only spatial-lite or shapefile.

Comment: And all the [Spatial Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database). [SpatiaLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpatiaLite) is a "file" Spatial Database, as the new standard of the OGC [GeoPackage](http://www.geopackage.org/): they use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a number of data formats within qgis, including PostGIS, based on PostgreSQL. Here's a topic describing [how to get started with PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/how-do-i-get-started-with-postgis).

Answer (score 2):

Have you worked through the QGIS training modules? I am not terribly familiar with QGIS either but it seems that QGIS relies on relational database management systems to create databases and access spatial data.  I am currently training myself how to use QGIS here are the links to the training about RDBMS for QGIS.

[Database concepts for PostGreSQL using QGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/database_concepts/index.html)

[Database concepts for PostGIS using QGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/index.html)